# Dynamic multiple grids asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I m working on a new project where everything comes from the database... including the name of the modules in the application + what is to be rendered on to the view... it's completely dynamic.. so there is a requirement where the controller passes collection of objects to the view and each object in the collection should be rendered as Grid, with editing enabled/disabled based on the current role... is there any way to achieve this in asp.net mvc 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom "Grid" HTML helper that renders the required html and use the request context to check if the user is in a particular security role.

```
public static string MyGrid(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    // use a StringBuilder to create your grid html        
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("MyRole"))
    {
        // add the edit bits to my string builder             
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Ok mark.. thanks for your answer... i m also thinking of using datatables on the client side for generating tables to grid